# how to replace value with content from database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this on my database table

id_a |   nama | email |

1 | philipe | philipe@mail.com |

2 | dora | dora@mail.com |

3 | John | john@mail.com  |

this code on my view

```
<tr>
<td><label for="cities">Select attendances</label></td>
<td> : </td>
<td>    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="id_c[]" title="click to select Attendances">
    <?php foreach ($test as $data): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data->id_a ?>" ><?php echo $data->nama ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select></td></tr>
```

in my code i have option value from my database = 1 2 3

what i want to do is send email, with an email address from my database

```
$id_c = $this->input->post('id_c');
        foreach($id_c as $id_a)
        {
        $query="SELECT email From mstr_attend WHERE id_a = ".$id_a.""; }
```

and here's the problem
what i get from this code is philipe@mail.comdora@mail.comjohn@mail.com

what i need is philipe@mail.com, dora@mail.com, john@mail.com

a comma after one email
can someone,give me some solution so i can get that

Comment: In which variable, you are storing the emails in foreach loop?

Comment: You didn't actually make any queries

Comment: does this code really match your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a string, you could loop into an array and then implode.

```
$emails = array();
foreach( $ids as $i )
{
  //do query here, then store in the emails array
  $emails[] = $query_output_email;
}

$comma_separated = implode( ', ', $emails ); //should output as email@dot.com, email@dot.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stated result using the following code:

```
$id_c = $this->input->post('id_c');
$all_id_c = implode(',', $id_c);
$this->db->select('group_concat(email) as emails');
$this->db->where('id_a IN ('.$all_id_c.')');
$query = $this->db->get('mstr_attend');    
$result = $query->row_array();
echo $result['emails']; // here is your result.
```

[This link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) will surely help you to generate the query result.

Comment: i get this error
Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) as emails FROM (`mstr_attend`) WHERE `0` = 'id_a IN (4, 3)'

Comment: so first implode $id_c, and then use group_concat to get email.....i copy your code but i get this error Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$emails

Comment: this what i get sir CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #29 [result_id] => Resource id #35 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 [row_data] => )

Comment: still get the error now from row()----Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::row()

Comment: i get the email when i use the comented code, thanks sir :D, but i still didn't know why the last two lines get the error

Comment: Your always welcome. Kindly delete all the comments from this answer. And marked it as Answer. Thanks